# IPrincipal.IsInRole() only works when I truncate the role names - why?

Tags: c#, .net, security, active-directory, iprincipal

I have an application that relies heavily on authorization of users. Within it, I am using `IPrincipal.IsInRole()` to check whether users are in the correct groups:

```
IPrincipal principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
bool inRole = principal.IsInRole("mydomainname\some role with a long name");
```

This works fine for the most part, but fails (returns an incorrect result) if the principal is an instance of a `WindowsPrincipal`. I have found that to make it work correctly, I have to truncate the name of the role that I pass in to be 32 characters long (including the domain name and the `\`):

```
IPrincipal principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal; // <- returns a WindowsPrincipal
bool inRole = principal.IsInRole("mydomainname\some role with a lo");
```

Truncating the role name then works correctly. Why? Is this a bug/feature/documented issue? I have an inkling that it may be related to Win2000 domains, but cannot find any info on it.

<sub>Some extra info:

This is a problem because the application can be configured to use either active directory or "custom" for its authorization ("custom" being any authorization provider that supports an interface - could be SQL-based, file-based, etc..). When custom is configured, the roles most likely do not need truncating and so I don't want to have to deal with this special case in my code. Additionally, I have another part of the application that uses classes in the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace to look up groups memberships. This requires the full role name and does not work if they are truncated.</sub>

Comment: Somebody once thought: "32 chars is enough for any role"

Comment: @Henk: I like it :) The characters being 32 makes it quite hard to search for as you get lots of hits for `Int32`, `Win32`, etc...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After much trial and error, I have figured out what is going on.

When a group is created in Active Directory, it is given two names:

[image]

It seems to be that **WindowsPrincipal uses the pre-Windows 2000 group name** when `IsInRole` is called.

After searching extensively, this does not seem to be documented anywhere. The closest I got was [this speculative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088041/active-directory-and-principalpermission/1089070#1089070) to a similar question here on SO.

---

In my case, the groups I was querying against on the domain had a long name, but a truncated pre-Windows 2000 name (truncated to 32 characters for some reason). Passing in the long name does not work as it was checking against the wrong group name.