# .Net Role Authentication PrincipalPermission fails

Tags: .net, vb.net, security, active-directory, principalpermission

I have a vb.net 3.5 application using PrincipalPermission class to ensure a user is a member of a role. The code works for some groups in Active Directory domain but not others. 
At first I thought the space was an issue but I checked 'Domain Users' which worked. Running this code I am a member of App Group.

```
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Security.Principal
Imports System.Security.Permissions

    Private Function DemandSecurity() As Boolean
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal)
        Dim principalGroup As New PrincipalPermission(Nothing, "App Group")
        Try
            principalGroup.Demand()
            Debug.Print("Demanding pricipal permissions for current user on 'App Group' role succeeded. ")
        Catch secEx As SecurityException
            Debug.Print("Security Exception - Demanding pricipal permissions for current user on 'App Group' role failed. ")

            Application.DoEvents()
            MessageBox.Show("Permission denied. Output: " & vbNewLine & secEx.ToString, "App - Security Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)

            Return False
            Exit Function
        End Try
        Return True
    End Function
```

The error output from secEx.ToString is

> "System.Security.SecurityException: Request for principal permission failed.
>      at System.Security.Permissions.PrincipalPermission.ThrowSecurityException()
>      at System.Security.Permissions.PrincipalPermission.Demand()
>      at App.My.MyApplication.DemandSecurity() in C:\Documents and Settings\me\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\App\App\ApplicationEvents.vb:line 28
>
> The action that failed was:
>   Demand
>   The type of the first permission that failed was:
>   System.Security.Permissions.PrincipalPermission
>
> The first permission that failed was:
>   IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.PrincipalPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
>   version="1">
>   Identity Authenticated="true"
>   Role="App Group"/>
>
> The demand was for:
>   IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.PrincipalPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
>   version="1">
>   Identity Authenticated="true"
>   Role="App Group"/>
>
> The assembly or AppDomain that failed was:
>   mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"

Let me know if I need to include anything else.

Comment: I have also tried using My.User.IsInRole which also returns false. I am definitely in the role.

Answer (score 0):

I think you better check your AD Groups to see this issue : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverDS/thread/3e8e9209-17c7-4674-8780-7ae09c607118

Comment: Thanks Jorge. The cn name matches the pre-windows 2000 name so that won't work. Unless I missed the point of that article.

Comment: To clarify, this does not answer the question. Hope someone can suggest what might be wrong with this.

Comment: @RussellHart the fact that you state that some searches fail and others not, is quite odd, smells like a naming problem as you stated in your info at the begginning, have you tried using an LDAP browser and querying for the objectSID instead of the name?

Comment: The groups which succeed are in CN=Users. The groups which fail are in OU=Security Groups in the same domain. How do you change the above code to demand on a groups in an organisational unit? Any pointers are much appreciated, please post as a new answer so I can accept. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok, this is just a wild guess, I happened to see this discussion regarding SAMAccountName and distinguished names, but no idea if this is still current issue:  [Active Directory and PrincipalPermission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088041/active-directory-and-principalpermission)

honestly I don't know if the "Role" can perform a full LDAP filter, but let's give it a try:
Let's suppose your group distinguished name is like this:

"CN=MyGroup,OU=SecurityGroups,OU=Department,DC=Company,DC=com"

why not trying this:

```
Role="CN=MyGroup,OU=SecurityGroups,OU=Department,DC=Company,DC=com"

Role=@"Company.com\Department\Security Groups\MyGroup"  // Not sure about this one though
```

And because this one seems more logic, maybe like this:

```
Role=@"Company\SAMAccountNameOfYourGroup"
```

I think your groups in CN=Users may succeed because probably they are in the root of your active directory, so for the other groups you may need to give either the SAMAccount which is unique, or give some structure for the search.